# GetProductInfo - pdwReturnedProductType Meaning (The product type)?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm creating a function to display Windows version string using [**GetProductInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx), and having some problem understanding the documentation about `pdwReturnedProductType` (The product type).

In the `Meaning` column it is stated for example that `PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL` means `Windows 10 Pro`, but this is true to Windows 7 as well.

`PRODUCT_EDUCATION` says `Windows 10 Education`; `PRODUCT_CORE` says `Windows 10 Home` (and so on) but is that can apply to other versions?

Is the `Windows 10` meant to be an example only? Are there any constants that meant to identify Windows 10 *only*?

Another example is `PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_SERVER` that means `Windows Home Server 2011`. is this apply only to Windows Home Server *2011*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, some of the Meaning columns are examples. You can verify this by looking at [an older version](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814195918/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx) of the documentation:

> PRODUCT_CORE  Windows 8

`PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_SERVER` only applies to 2011 (the only other home server release was 2003 R2 before the Premium SKU existed). Microsoft might release another home server in the future but it seems unlikely at this point.

`GetProductInfo` takes a version number as input because it tries to map newer values created after your application has been released:

> Subsequent releases of Windows will map the product types it supports to the set of product types supported by each supported previous release of Windows, back to version 6.0.0.0. Therefore, an application that does an equality test for any of these values will continue to work on future releases, even when new product types are added.